# Need to modify array as per specific requirement in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am working in typescript where I need to modify an array to some specific pattern.

Here is my array:

```
["sunday","monday","tuesday"]
```

This is what I need it to be like:

```
["day:Sunday","day:Monday","day:Tuesday"]
```

I have already tried map method like this:

```
result = arr.map(x => ({day: x}));
```

But map gives me result some different which is not needed:

```
[{"day":"sunday"},{"day":"monday"},{"day":"tuesday"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to prepend the strings and to change the first letter to upper:

```js
const arr = ["sunday","monday","tuesday"];
const result = arr.map(x => 'day:' + x[0].toUpperCase() + x.slice(1));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are adding those brackets, here's a solution:

```js
const original = ["sunday","monday","tuesday"]
console.log(original)
  
const result = original.map(day => `day:${day}`);
console.log(result)

//["day:sunday", "day:monday", "day:tuesday"]
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't produce the expected result `["day:Sunday","day:Monday","day:Tuesday"]` and you should use `let`/`const` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Array map is the right method, you just need to return a string, not an object:

```
result = arr.map(d => `day:${d.toUpperCase()}`)
```

Comment: This answer changes all characters, not only the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
const days = ["sunday","monday","tuesday"];

const dayFun = days.map((day) => {
  const dayUppercase = day.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + day.slice(1);
  return `day:${dayUppercase}`;
});

console.log(dayFun);
```